# Combinations of Combinations

Tags: python

There are nearly 14 million combinations from a selection of 6 numbers from a range of 1-49. From the 14 million, I've cut the combinations down to 8.9 million by selecting only those where the sum of the 6 number combination must equate to between 120 and 180.

Example: 5, 10, 20, 27, 29, 40  = 131

Of the remaining 8.9 million combinations, I'm trying to remove all combinations that contain less than 2 and more than 4 odd numbers.

Basically, I want Python to show me how many combinations of those 8.9 million combinations have between 2-4 odd numbers in their combinations. All combinations of only 1 or less odd numbers and 5 or more odd numbers would be excluded from the results.

Example: 5, 10, 20, 27, 32, 40 = 2 odd numbers (it would be included in the amount of combinations).

Thank you!

```
import functools

_MIN_SUM     = 120
_MAX_SUM     = 180
_MIN_NUM     = 1
_MAX_NUM     = 49
_NUM_CHOICES = 6

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(n, l, s):
    assert(all(isinstance(v, int) and v >= 0 for v in (n, l, s)))
    return 0 if s > _MAX_SUM else (
        int(s >= _MIN_SUM) if n == 0 else (
            sum(f(n-1, i+1, s+i) for i in range(l, _MAX_NUM+1))
        )
    )

result = f(_NUM_CHOICES, _MIN_NUM, 0)

print('Number of choices = {}'.format(result))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Just what is your question for us? If you are asking us for a routine to do that count, is brute force (trying all combinations and counting those that meet your conditions) acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do almost exactly the same as you are currently doing. Just add a parameter that counts how many odd numbers there are and increase it when you add an odd. Then you can adjust your tests accordingly:

```
import functools

_MIN_SUM     = 120
_MAX_SUM     = 180
_MIN_NUM     = 1
_MAX_NUM     = 49
_NUM_CHOICES = 6
_MIN_ODDS    = 2
_MAX_ODDS    = 4

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(n, l, s = 0, odds = 0):
    if s > _MAX_SUM or odds > _MAX_ODDS:
        return 0
    if n == 0 :
        return int(s >= _MIN_SUM and odds >= _MIN_ODDS)
    return sum(f(n-1, i+1, s+i, odds + i % 2) for i in range(l, _MAX_NUM+1))


result = f(_NUM_CHOICES, _MIN_NUM)

print('Number of choices = {}'.format(result))
```

Because it's memoized and prunes branches, this runs quickly:

```
150 ns ± 13 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Running it with the more managable:

```
_MIN_SUM     = 1
_MAX_SUM     = 8
_MIN_NUM     = 1
_MAX_NUM     = 8
_NUM_CHOICES = 2
_MIN_ODDS    = 2
_MAX_ODDS    = 4
```

returns `4` which corresponds to the set:

```
(1, 3),
(1, 5),
(1, 7),
(3, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for - your method shows the same result as the other answer except your method shows the result much, much faster!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the combinations() function from itertools and just brutally count the combinations that are eligible:

```
from itertools import combinations

eligible = 0
for combo in combinations(range(1,50),6):
    total = sum(combo)
    if total < 120 or total > 180:
        continue
    odds = sum(n&1 for n in combo)
    if odds < 2 or odds > 4:
        continue
    eligible += 1

print(eligible) # 7221936
```

*It only takes a few seconds (10-12)*